# Generate php array to use on js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Table:

```
--------------------
Product  |   Price
--------------------
apples   |  5
oranges  |  6
peaches  |  7
```

how can i get rows from table and generate an json array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What is `js array`??

Comment: so you want us to write everything for you? from mysql query -> php -> up to javascript??

Comment: eg: { "myproducts": [{ "products": "apples", "price": "5"},{ "products": "oranges", "price": "6"}] }

Comment: It's json not an array!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `fetch` data from `table` and use `json_encode`:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','yourdatabase') or die("Could not connect database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from youtable");
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$arr['myproducts'][] = $row;    
    }
    $js_array = json_encode($arr);
    echo $js_array;
?>
```

Output:

```
{"myproducts":[{"price":"4","products":"apples"},{"price":"5","products":"oranges"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simple just do `SQL SELECT` and then the result of it should be `json_encode()`

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
```

Afther this in your code:

```
while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $newArr[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($newArr);
```